# Having issues with y-scrollable column with JQuery UI Sortable Connect Lists example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**What I am trying to do:** I am trying to create a Drag-Drop-Sort grid. Followed the same example as JQuery UI Sortable Connect Lists.

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

**My Code Example:** My version of the above example is as below JSFiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/t60x6j2b/5/

**JS Code**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

**CSS**

```
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            width: 147px;
            min-height: 20px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 0 0 0;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
            height:500px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        #sortable1 div, #sortable2 div {
            margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            width: 120px;
            height: 50px !important;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="title">Column 1</div>
<div id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 1</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 2</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 3</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 4</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 5</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 6</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 7</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 8</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 9</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 10</div>
</div>
<div class="title">Column 2</div>
<div id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item A</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item B</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item C</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item D</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item E</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item F</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item G</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item H</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item I</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item J</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item K</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item L</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item M</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item N</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item O</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item P</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item Q</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item R</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item S</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item T</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item U</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item V</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item W</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item X</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item Y</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item Z</div>
</div>
```

As you can see not a lot of difference between my code and jquery ui example.

**My problem:** Now, my issues is when I drag say Item 1 from column 1 and try and drop in between Item M and Item N on column 2(which are obviously hidden under the scroller), I needed the column 2 scroller to get activated and start scrolling. But rather it scrolls the column 1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Karthik

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can target the `scrollParent` property of the scrollable instance and change it on the `over` event. This is what's being used in jquery-ui to calculate scrolling. It probably should be default behavior, but for some reason it doesn't look like it is.

See this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/x88m3L9z/):

```js
$(function () {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        over: function (e, ui) {
            $(ui.sender).sortable('instance').scrollParent = $(e.target)
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.title {
    float:left;
}
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 147px;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height:500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#sortable1 div, #sortable2 div {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="title">Column 1</div>
<div id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 1</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 2</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 3</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 4</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 5</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 6</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 7</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 8</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 9</div>
    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 10</div>
</div>
<div class="title">Column 2</div>
<div id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item A</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item B</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item C</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item D</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item E</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item F</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item G</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item H</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item I</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item J</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item K</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item L</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item M</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item N</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item O</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item P</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item Q</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item R</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item S</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item T</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item U</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item V</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item W</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item X</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item Y</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item Z</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this is 5 years old / but My issue is scrolling the parent container horizontally? I tried with calculations of the element's position left/right, but it's super dirty... any true/tried solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move a helper into the other list like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/t60x6j2b/6/

```
$('.connectedSortable').sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    helper: function (event, element) {
        return element.clone().appendTo($('.connectedSortable').not(element.parent()));
    }
});
```