# jQuery UI Sortable - Multi Connected List Drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Using jQuery UI Sortable, [there is an option to have the sortable item container scroll when an item is dragged](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-scroll).

I have multiple sortable lists connected in separate containers with max heights and overflow scrolls:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">A1</div>
  <div class="item">A2</div>
  <div class="item">A3</div>
  <div class="item">A4</div>
  <div class="item">A5</div>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <div class="item">B1</div>
  <div class="item">B2</div>
  <div class="item">B3</div>
  <div class="item">B4</div>
  <div class="item">B5</div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to scroll each container when items are dragged between them.

Currently, dragging only scrolls the parent container - we need it to be able to scroll connected list containers.

See this codepen for basic setup:
http://codepen.io/typ90/pen/pymOdV

I've tried using the helper option on sortable to clone the item and append to other containers as it's dragged around with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is more like a feature request to the original plugin. Try raising one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having issues with y-scrollable column with JQuery UI Sortable Connect Lists example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193912/having-issues-with-y-scrollable-column-with-jquery-ui-sortable-connect-lists-exa)

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the code below to your `sortable` configuration section:

```
over: function (e, ui) {
  $(ui.sender).sortable('instance').scrollParent = $(e.target)
}
```

It will be like that:

```
$('.list').sortable({
  items: '.item',
  connectWith: '.list',
  over: function (e, ui) {
    $(ui.sender).sortable('instance').scrollParent = $(e.target)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with helper and clone

```
$('.list').sortable({
  connectWith: '.list',
  placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
  helper: function (event, element) {
    return element.clone().appendTo($('.connectedSortable').not(element.parent()));
  }
});
```

in my case the use of only option "clone" was not possible because of z-index issue with sort element.

credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2117156/jamie-barker

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was not the solution in my case with the same problem as the OP. I was getting errors with the accepted answer.

However, it was very close. I simply needed to check that `ui.sender` was a truthy value.

```
$('.list').sortable({
  items: '.item',
  connectWith: '.list',
  over: function (e, ui) {
    if (ui.sender) {
      $(ui.sender).sortable('instance').scrollParent = $(e.target)
    }
  }
});
```